# Is there any way to get a Facebook "Like Box" to include posts by other than the page owner

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

I'm looking after a fairly stodgy rather static website for an organization which (now) also has a Facebook "page" with a bit more of a community buzz around it.

I added a Facebook "Like Box" to the old site.  While it's a nice attractor for the Facebook "page" through the "Like button", count and the photos of the community, I'm a bit disappointed the "stream" component of it (so far as I can tell) only shows posts by the page identity, which are relatively boring compared with what you have if you added the comments and "posts by others" from the community active on the Facebook page.

Is there any way of getting this additional content into the Like Box ?

I already tried adding '`&amp;force_wall=true`' to the like box iframe parameters to no effect - in any case the page isn't for a place; it's for "Companies & Organizations" - so if this isn't controllable through the API I do wonder if there's something I can tweak in the FB page admin settings ?  Or is it just not an option at all ?

Answer (score 2):

Researched for the same, but no success. The closest you can get is through [Activity Feed plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/), that too only if you have an App Page. So, the only option left is to get whole page feed using the Graph API and then parse it accordingly.

Ex: https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed?access_token=your_access_token